# C# Mail - Separate Sender and Return Path

Tags: c#, .net, email

I am attempting to set a different return path and sender in the headers to replicate a previous PHP system. It needs to be exactly the same.

When I put in a Sender it sets this to the return path and I can't seem to find a solution to separate these. Also the sender shows as behalf of in the From part of the mail message which I do not want.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Add your code here please?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("sender@email.com", "to@email.com");    
mail.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress("reply@email.com", "reply-to"));
```

Please note `MailMessage.ReplyTo` is now obsolete.

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.replytolist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`MailMessage.ReplyTo` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.replyto.aspx).

> Use the ReplyTo property to indicate an address other than the From address to use to reply to this message.

Answer (score 0):

I used the MailKit library to solve my issue.

This allows you to specify a different sender at server level